# Can't get string inside ATag

Tags: html, string, parsing, beautifulsoup, atag

I am a beginner, so please be kind. I'm using Beautiful Soup to parse through some html. I have gotten to where i found this a tag

```
a_tag = <a href="sicc2020/results?pid=31022">S<span class="notCompact">hakira</span> Mirfin</a>
```

I would like to get "S" "hakira" and "Mirfin" out of this string. However when I use the .string function, it just says none. I can get the 'hakira' part, but i can't get the "S" or "Mirfin".

```
print(a_tag)
>><a href="sicc2020/results?pid=31022">S<span class="notCompact">hakira</span> Mirfin</a>

print(a_tag).string
>> None

print(a_tag).find('span').string
>>hakira
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc="""<a href="sicc2020/results?pid=31022">S<span class="notCompact">hakira</span> Mirfin</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
text = soup.find("a").get_text(",", strip=True)

print(text)
```

Output will be:

```
S,hakira,Mirfin
```

Comment: Thank you! get_text worked! didn't realize there was a difference between that and .string. thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do that :

```
var text_array;
var children = document.getElementById(id).childNodes;

text_array.push(document.getElementById(id).textContent)

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    text_array.push(children[i].textContent)
  }
```

if you want to remove all the content :

```
var children = document.getElementById(id).childNodes;

document.getElementById(id).textContent = ""

  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].textContent = ""
  }
```

If it's dont work for your "S" and "Mirfin", you can do that :

```
$("#id")
.clone()    //clone the element
.children() //select all the children
.remove()   //remove all the children
.end()  //again go back to selected element
.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html ='''<a href="sicc2020/results?pid=31022">S<span class="notCompact">hakira</span> Mirfin</a>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.a.text)
```

Result:

```
Shakira Mirfin
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples